# Styled-Components, how to dynamically generate css properties?

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

**Given two dynamic properties:**

1. currentColor
2. cardsRemaining

And `const colors = ['blue', 'red', 'green', 'yellow', 'orange']`

With Styled components, how can I dynamically set the box-shadow property? Where the number cardsRemaining assigns the number of box-shadow values.

**For example, cardsRemaining == 2:**

```
box-shadow:
    8px 0 0 0 colors[current+1],
    16px 0 0 0 colors[current+2];
```

**For example, cardsRemaining == 4:**

```
box-shadow:
    8px 0 0 0 colors[current+1],
    16px 0 0 0 colors[current+2],
    24px 0 0 0 colors[current+3],
    32px 0 0 0 colors[current+4];
```

And where `currentColor` is used to assign the color in each box-shadow value.

**So if cardsRemaining == 4 && currentColor == blue:**

```
box-shadow:
    8px 0 0 0 red,
    16px 0 0 0 green,
    24px 0 0 0 yellow,
    32px 0 0 0 orange;
```

**Or, if cardsRemaining == 2 && currentColor == yellow:**

```
box-shadow:
    8px 0 0 0 orange,
    16px 0 0 0 blue;
```

How would you approach a problem like this with styled-components?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write a function that will return the styling given the properties as arguments.
here you go: [solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-a1yvht)

Answer (score 2):

Inside styled components, it is possible to access the props. Therefore, you can do something like below -

```
export getBoxShadow = ({cardsRemaining, currentColor }) => logicHere

export const StyledComponent = styled.div`box-shadow: ${getBoxShadow};`
```

Edit from @OwlyMoly: If you just want to pass the color:

```
    const StyledComponent = styled.div`
     box-shadow: 8px 0 0 0 ${props => props.colorToBe}
    `
```